# How to list all links of google search result with selenium-python?

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.clear()
search.send_keys("tesla")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)

url_list = []

results_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for url in results_list:
    
    if url == None:
        pass
    else:
        url_list.append(url.get_attribute("href"))
```

I want to capture screenshots of all websites that are results of google search. However, with this code, my program grab "videos, shopping, news, Images" buttons links. But, I just want to grab resulted links. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's so much different but it's the exact thing that you want :)

```
for i in range(len(results_list)):
    results_list[i] = results_list[i].text.replace(">", "/").replace("›", "/").replace(" ", "")
    if not validators.url(results_list[i]):
        results_list[i] = ''

results_list = list(filter(None, results_list))

print(results_list)
```

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import validators


fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=fireFoxOptions, executable_path='./geckodriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=tesla")
results_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('cite')

for i in range(len(results_list)):
    results_list[i] = results_list[i].text.replace(">", "/").replace("›", "/").replace(" ", "")
    if not validators.url(results_list[i]):
        results_list[i] = ''

results_list = list(filter(None, results_list))

print(results_list)
driver.quit()
```